# Actionbar progress indicator and refresh button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to show the progress indicator (the one that is show using requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) in place of a refresh button?

The idea is to work as Gmail client does: When not loading show refresh button and when loading show the indeterminate spinner in the place of refresh button

Answer (score 53):

Yes you can do it easily this way.

```
private MenuItem refresh;
.
.
.

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // refresh menu item
    refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh_option_item);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You have to get your refresh menu item like above and then, you can enable spinning item like below:

```
refresh.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
```

and when you task is completed, you can disable spinning like below:

```
refresh.setActionView(null);
```

And lastly, the `actionbar_indeterminate_progress.xml` can be like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that sometimes that reference is null and you'll get npe. Don't know how to reproduce it but it's happening for me. I used your same approach....

Comment: I did not happen for at least once. When your menu is created refresh variable is created. User clicking that refresh button means that of course it was created earlier.

Comment: With some adaptations it works like a charm! And it is better than the default wheel.

Comment: Excellent code, been looking for this for hours. Thanks! And to avoid the NPE, when someone pushes the refreshMenuItem check if the actionView is null, if it is then you know that the animation is rolling.

Comment: Yes exactly, if the actionview is not null, you know that it is spinning.

Comment: It's better to use refresh.collapseActionView() and expandActionView() and set the action view just once

Comment: I'm having this problem: ?android:attr/indeterminateProgressStyle requires API level 11. Any way to get this solution to work for Api 10?

Comment: Actually you are right. The new lint checks do not let you add that line. Just remove it and set the spinner to be indeterminate programatically.

Comment: My problem is (I use a Galaxy Nexus), that when it changes the states it moves a bit from left to right. Did anybody have this problem?

Comment: where can I get id of refresh_option_item ?

Comment: When targeting APIs below 11, use the MenuItemCompat.setActionView() method.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the follow: put both the refresh button and the indeterminate spinner inside a  `FrameLayout`, so the two are stacked in the z-plane, show in the same position on the screen. Then you just have to play with the Visibility. When you want to show the refresh button, you set the spinner to invisible and the button to visible. When you want to show the spinner, set it to visible and the button to invisible.

Comment: I know how I can layout that manually but I want to do this in actionbar.

Comment: Isn't it my answer useful to you? You did not even comment on it. :)

Comment: Is it possible to swap with a broadcast intent?